# ABAddressBookSave causing a EXC_BAD_ACCESS ARC Enabled

Tags: ios, objective-c, abaddressbook

The code I had been written was working until I tried to move the saving to a new thread.
in ViewController.h I assigned an ABAddressBookRef:

```
ViewController.h

ABAddressBookRef addressBook;
```

and in ViewController.m file created an addressbook object

```
ViewController.m
addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, anError);
/// ... getting a person name and modify it. the code is OK. tested before the NSThread thing
NSThread *saveThread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(saveAddressBook:) object:(__bridge id)addressBook];                     
[saveThread start];
```

and the saveThread method is:

```
- (void)saveAddressBook:(id)ab
{
    bool didSave;   
    CFErrorRef error = NULL;

    didSave = ABAddressBookSave((__bridge ABAddressBookRef)ab, &error);
    if (didSave) { NSLog(@"Saved.");}

}
```

ABAddressBookSave line crashes the app:

> Thread 6: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (Code=1,address=0x65504289)

I know the error is because of a memory failure but I can't release anything since I'm using ARC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be because you cannot share an instance of ABAddressBookRef across multiple threads (see this [Why would ABAddressbookRef need to be created for each thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013411/why-would-abaddressbookref-need-to-be-created-for-each-thread)).